# MDI Tab names changing back... / Taskbar Preview not selecting

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, mdi

I'm creating an MDI application, WITHOUT the Document/View.
I am also using MDITabbedGroups.

I had a problem, because I have to name may tabs dynamically (names are in the DB and user created), meaning I couldn't use resources for the names.
I create all the tabs as 'Program name', then rename them by calling the following after create:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CChildView, CWnd)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_SET_COLOR, CCOnSetColor)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, (WPARAM)ID_SET_COLOR);

void CChildView::CCOnSetColor()
{
    CMDIChildWndEx* pFrame = (CMDIChildWndEx*)GetParent();
    CMFCTabCtrl* pTabCtrl = pFrame->GetRelatedTabGroup();
    if (pTabCtrl != NULL)
    {
        pTabCtrl->SetTabBkColor(pTabCtrl->GetActiveTab(), GetTabCol());
        pTabCtrl->SetTabLabel(pTabCtrl->GetActiveTab(), GetTabName());
        pTabCtrl->RedrawWindow();
    }
}
```

But the problem was that when I switched tabs the names would change back to 'Program Name'.

I managed to avoid this by skipping over CMDIChildWndEx in the OnMDIActivate call as so:

```
void CChildFrame::OnMDIActivate(BOOL bActivate, CWnd* activated, CWnd* disbled)
{
    CWnd::OnMDIActivate(bActivate, activated, disbled);
}
```

I know, I know, bad. However:

This worked fine, all other functionality seemed to be working, tabs were switching, active window was correct etc etc...

Until I noticed that on mouse over of the task bar, I got a preview of all open tabs, and if I clicked on one of the inactive tabs things went wrong.
Now the active frame / view (GetActiveFrame() / GetActiveView() in MainFrame) was the one I click on, but it is not drawn and the tab not switched to.

So I tried:

```
void CChildFrame::OnMDIActivate(BOOL bActivate, CWnd* activated, CWnd* disbled)
{
    CMDIChildWndEx::OnMDIActivate(bActivate, activated, disbled);
    CMFCTabCtrl* pTabCtrl = GetRelatedTabGroup();
    if (pTabCtrl != NULL)
    {
        pTabCtrl->SetTabBkColor(pTabCtrl->GetActiveTab(), m_wndView.GetTabCol());
        pTabCtrl->SetTabLabel(pTabCtrl->GetActiveTab(), m_wndView.GetTabName());
        //  pTabCtrl->SetTabIcon(pTabCtrl->GetActiveTab(), 2);
        pTabCtrl->RedrawWindow();
    }
}
```

&&&

```
void CChildFrame::OnMDIActivate(BOOL bActivate, CWnd* activated, CWnd* disbled)
{
    CMDIChildWndEx::OnMDIActivate(bActivate, activated, disbled);
    m_wndView.PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, (WPARAM)ID_SET_COLOR);
    if(disbled) ((CChildFrame*)disbled)->m_wndView.PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, (WPARAM)ID_SET_COLOR);
}
```

Now the tab switches correctly, but only the tab being activated gets the correct name, all inactive tabs go back to 'Program Name'
interestingly the color remains correct.

So the Question:
Can I permanently change the name some how / where.
I saw in MS Documentation that it can be set in CDocument, but I don't have a Document...
Alternatively what call / calls do I need to catch to set my name every time?

Also Bonus Q:
Can I make the Preview show only the 'Active' Tab, and not the others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much hunting around in the AFX source files, I found this:

```
CString CMDIChildWndEx::GetFrameText() const
{
    ASSERT_VALID(this);

    CString strText;
    GetWindowText(strText);

    return strText;
}
```

& this

```
void CMDIFrameWnd::OnUpdateFrameTitle(BOOL bAddToTitle)
{
    if ((GetStyle() & FWS_ADDTOTITLE) == 0)
        return;     // leave it alone!
    ... // rest of func
}
```

so it is as simple as removing the style flag the MS puts in automatically (via wizard create project), on the func `BOOL PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs)`.
Then setting the title of the Frame via `SetWindowText(title);`